# Magento does not install my module

Tags: magento-1.6

I have a very weird situation where my Magento Module is not getting installed, but its getting registered.

This is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_Module>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Example_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <example_module>
                <class>Example_Module_Helper</class>
            </example_module>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <example_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Example_Module</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </example_module_setup>
            <example_module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </example_module_write>
            <example_module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </example_module_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Any I have the following subdirectory structure:

```
Example /
- Module /
-- data / example_module_setup / data-install-0.1.0.php 
-- data / example_module_setup / data-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php
-- etc / config.xml
-- sql / example_module_setup / install-0.1.0.php
```

However, the module does not get registered in `core_resource`. I've cleared var/cache before reloading the frontend.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commited all my changes to Git and switched to the master branch, cleared the cache and reloaded the frontend once.

After that I've switched back to my branch, which then executed finally the install scripts. Seems like there was a hickup at some point and changing the Git branches helped to sort that out.